# Why I'm not getting array values as options in select control in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, html-select

I've an array titled `$volume_unit_list` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [unit] => Microsecond
            [created_at] => 1397479783
            [updated_at] => 1397479783
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [unit] => oz
            [created_at] => 1397548900
            [updated_at] => 1397672502
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [unit] => ml
            [created_at] => 1397641838
            [updated_at] => 1397672480
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [unit] => L
            [created_at] => 1397672517
            [updated_at] => 1397672517
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [unit] => gms
            [created_at] => 1398196412
            [updated_at] => 1398196412
        )

)
```

The select code to display the array values is as follows:

```
echo "<tr id='reb$rebate_no'>
        <td>
           <input type='text' name='pack[]' value='' class='form-control' size='8'/>
        <td>
        <div class='btn-group'>
        <select id='unit' name='units[]' class='form-control'>
           <option value=''  if $data.id=='' selected='selected'{/if}>Select Unit</option>
           foreach ($volume_unit_list as $key=>$value)
             <option value=$key[id]>$key[unit]</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>";
```

Can someone please correct the mistake I'm making in displaying array values in select control?

Comment: Please reformat the php code and add the HTML output of the script.

Comment: Is this just straight PHP or are you using Smarty or some similiar engine?

Comment: @RiggsFolly:Yes I'm using smarty but the above code is for php only.

Answer (score 0):

You will see the error easier if you lay your code out in a more readable fashion.

The foreach loop cannot be executed if it is in a quoted literal. You need to terminate the string and then run the loop and then complete the string.

```
echo "<tr id='reb$rebate_no'>
        <td>
           <input type='text' name='pack[]' value='' class='form-control' size='8'/>
<-- Missing </td> -->
        <td>
        <div class='btn-group'>
        <select id='unit' name='units[]' class='form-control'>
           <option value=''  if $data.id=='' selected='selected'{/if}>Select Unit</option>";

<?php
    foreach ($volume_unit_list as $key=>$value) {
        echo '<option value="' . $key['id'] . '">' . $key['unit'] . '</option>';
    }
?>
echo "</select>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>";
```

Comment: You just tell me what's wrong in following code?
foreach ($volume_unit_list as $key=>$value)
             <option value=$key[id]>$key[unit]</option>

Comment: Breaking the foreach loop out of the string and running it inside a `<?php ... ?>`. Otherwise it wont actually run anything.